# How can I use the thor 'run' method outside of a thor class?

Tags: ruby, command-line, thor

There was a related question but I think it's for an older version of thor because it does not work anymore.

Basically the situation is I have a thor class. This class has many standard thor commands. What I wanted to do was break out the logic of those commands into other classes so I can test the code easier.

So I created a `Command` class that does not inherit from thor. It looks something like this:

`command.rb`

```
class Command
  include Thor::Base
  include Thor::Actions

  # initializer has only a few arguments, all app specific and not related to thor

  def foo
    run 'which ps'
  end
end
```

When I run `foo` from my main thor class the output is nothing at all, it's empty. Here's the main thor class:

`cli.rb`

```
require 'thor'

class CLI < Thor
  def hello
    require 'command'
    Command.new().foo
  end
end
```

If I cut the code from `foo` and place it into `hello` and move the `include Thor::Actions` into the main thor class then it works.

Both files are really name spaced under the same module but I removed that from the code examples here to minimize cruft.

**How can I get this to work so I can use all of the action module's methods in a non-thor class?**

I tried messing around with source/destinations roots and destination stack which was in the related question but they don't work anymore it seems.